# Integrity Constraint Violation When Attaching to Delete

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

I'm about done with that hours-editor I've been bugging everyone about.  I just need to get it to delete things now:  either a wholesale hours-schedule deletion or deleting ExceptionHoursSets (exceptions to a general hours pattern).  Each ExceptionHoursSet has a WeekSpec, which in turn has a collection of DaySpecs (containing the hours for the day).  So I obviously want to loop through each exception set, and delete the days, week, and set that have been marked for removal.  Here's the abbreviated method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Schedule schedule, [Bind(Prefix = "ExceptionHoursSet")] List<ExceptionHoursSet> exceptionHoursSets)
    {
        using (var db = new HoursDb())
        {
            ViewBag.DayNames = HomeServices.DayNames;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                schedule.ExceptionHoursSets = exceptionHoursSets;
                foreach (var exceptionHoursSet in exceptionHoursSets)
                {
                    if (!exceptionHoursSet.IsDeleting)
                    {
                        exceptionHoursSet.WeekSpecId = exceptionHoursSet.WeekSpec.WeekSpecId;
                            // for coherency (should this be necessary?)

                        foreach (var daySpec in exceptionHoursSet.WeekSpec.DaySpecs)
                        {
                            db.Entry(daySpec).State = EntityState.Modified;
                            db.SaveChanges();
                        }
                        db.Entry(exceptionHoursSet.WeekSpec).State = EntityState.Modified;
                        db.SaveChanges();

                        db.Entry(exceptionHoursSet).State = EntityState.Modified;
                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var daySpecs = new List<DaySpec>(exceptionHoursSet.WeekSpec.DaySpecs);

                        db.ExceptionHoursSets.Attach(exceptionHoursSet);
                        db.WeekSpecs.Attach(exceptionHoursSet.WeekSpec);
                        foreach (var daySpec in daySpecs)
                        {
                            db.DaySpecs.Attach(daySpec);
                            db.DaySpecs.Remove(daySpec);
                        }
                        db.WeekSpecs.Remove(exceptionHoursSet.WeekSpec);
                        db.ExceptionHoursSets.Remove(exceptionHoursSet);

                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }

                if (HasEditedException(lastExceptionHoursSet))
                {
                    var dayNum = 0;
                    foreach (var daySpec in lastExceptionHoursSet.WeekSpec.DaySpecs)
                    {
                        daySpec.DayNum = dayNum++;
                        daySpec.DaySpecId = Guid.NewGuid();
                        db.DaySpecs.Add(daySpec);
                    }
                    lastExceptionHoursSet.WeekSpec.WeekSpecId = Guid.NewGuid();
                    db.WeekSpecs.Add(lastExceptionHoursSet.WeekSpec);
                    lastExceptionHoursSet.ExceptionHoursSetId = Guid.NewGuid();
                    exceptionHoursSets.Add(lastExceptionHoursSet);
                    db.ExceptionHoursSets.Add(lastExceptionHoursSet);
                }

                db.Entry(schedule).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(schedule);
        }
    }
```

The error I get when trying to attach to the exceptionHoursSet I attempt to delete is this:

A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property values that define the referential constraints are not consistent between principal and dependent objects in the relationship.

What is this?  And more to the point, how do I get rid of it?

Thanks for putting up with me,
Nathan Bond

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, found it.  First I needed to attach the Schedule the exception sets were part of.  Then I got the same error for that attachment, but it was because I had not done some matter of making things integrated within the Schedule's props, work done in code I had abbreviated out of the listing above.  Essentially, I also have a WeekSpec property for the Schedule as well as exception sets, which holds the general hours pattern.  When I got the Schedule parameter from the view, the Schedule had its ID and its general hours WeekSpec, which also had its own ID.  However, the Schedule's foreign key for its WeekSpec was not set; only after I set it to the WeekSpec's ID could I effectively attach.  So, all I had to do was move the Schedule attachment code to after this ID matching, and everything works silver.  Sorry for a silly question.